# Implementing Mobile application management in iOS?

Tags: ios, mobile

We are trying to implement mobile application management for our enterprise application.

We tried using paid MAM service for our purposes but it did not work. Is there anybody who has used some open source MAM solutions or any other way to go around this problem?

Comment: You haven't explained what your problem is.

Comment: @Paulw11 we need to implement MAM, and the services we are using are not allowing remote management for the other enterprise apps. So is there any other alternative that can be done?